# How to set upload_path in code igniter as url?

Tags: api, codeigniter, file-upload

Helloo....
I have a problem uploading the image in the code igniter.
I use codeigniter as backend.
the code is like this:

```
public function upload_image_post()
{
    if ($_FILES['image']) {
        $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $this->load->library('upload', array(
            'overwrite' => FALSE,
            'upload_path' => FCPATH . 'assets/public/image/news',
            'max_size' => '2097152',
            'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|gif|jpeg',
        ));

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            return  $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'fail 1'
            ], 500);
        } else {
            $upload = $this->upload->data();
            return  $this->response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'success',
                'data' => $upload,
            ], 200);
        }
    } else {
        return  $this->response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'fail 2'
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

When i using it in localhost, it is success to upload image. But when i deploy it, its failed, and show message 'fail 1'

how do I set up upload_path so it can point to any url I want??

Comment: Can you change `'message' => 'fail 1'` for `'message' => $this->upload->display_errors()` ? this can give you an idea about why is the upload failing. While you do that, check the upload directory exists, has write permissions (try CHMODing it to 775 and retry) and is accesible by your PHP process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's uploading on your localhost your logic is probably right.Please try the following see if this helps you.

1. First of all can you try adding a trailing slash to the path you provided like this `assets/public/image/news/`
2. Please check if your upload folder has write permissions set.
   Note:
   You can check if your directory is writable using this piece of code from this link.

> https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-74330.html

```
<?php if(is_writable(base_url('assets/public/image/news/'))){
    echo 'writable';
}
else { echo  (base_url('assets/public/image/news/'). ' ' ."is not writable");} ?>
```

3. Check if your htaccess is configured properly. May be any htaccess from the following git repository might work for you if the above points does not work.

> https://github.com/tasmanwebsolutions/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @KUMAR sorry for the delayed replay still if you are looking for an anwser this function return true or false on if the string path you provided is writable respectively. The path can be of a file or directory. You can read about it in detail at.
```https://www.php.net/is_writable```